# Spring Boot bean creation/injection issue

Tags: spring-boot, autowired, spring-bean

I have spring boot application where I am stuck not sure what's wrong in my code. It gives me error of beans creation. I have used @Autowired, but not sure what's wrong.

Main.Java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

UserWS.java

```
@Controller
public class UserWS
{

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = URLConstants.ADD, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Status> add(@RequestBody User user) throws PeerRateException
    {
        try
        {
            userService.addUser(user);
            Status status = PeerUtils.getSuccessStatus();
            status.setObject(null);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(status, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            throw new PeerRateException(ExceptionConstants.USER_CREATE_CODE, ExceptionConstants.USER_CREATE, t);
        }
    }
}
```

UserService.Java

```
@Component
public class UserService
{

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    public void addUser(User user)
    {
        userDao.save(user);
    }

}
```

UserDao.java

```
@Transactional
public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<User, Long>
{

}
```

**EDIT**

```
com.hk.peerrate.main
    Main.java
com.hk.peerrate.service
    UserService.java
com.hk.peerrate.ws
    UserWS.java
```

Comment: This is the error : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't displayed the package where all above class resides, I can only assume that the problem is with your Project structure.

The `UserService` class could be outside of the `@ComponentScan`.

Now `@SpringBootApplication` is same as `@Configuration @EnableAutoConfiguration @ComponentScan` together, so make sure that the `UserService.java` is under the same package or sub-package of your `Application.java`.

Have a look at the this [Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html) doc.

Comment: Yup, I was correct. Its the issue with you package. You can simply move your `Application.java` to `com.hk.peerrate` package, so that `@ComponentScan` will be applied to all other classes as they would fall under sub-package.

Comment: Changed package structure like you said, but still

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.hk.peerrate.dao.UserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: Did you move your `UserDao.java` under the `Application.java` sub-package?

I think you might wanna set the repository class like this `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.hk.peerrate.dao")` over `Application.java`

Comment: In case you are interested, check my experiments with Spring Social Twitter and Spring-Boot on [Github](https://github.com/RawSanj/Spring-Twitter-Stream/tree/dataJpa).